# Need urllib.urlretrieve and urllib2.OpenerDirector together

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2, urllib

I'm writing a script in Python 2.7 which uses a `urllib2.OpenerDirector` instance via `urllib2.build_opener()` to take advantage of the `urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor` class, because I need to store and re-send the cookies I get:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar()))
```

However, after making several requests and moving the cookies around, eventually I need to retrieve a list of URLs. I wanted to use `urllib.urlretrieve()` because I read it downloads the file in chunks, but I cannot because I need to carry my cookies on the request and
`urllib.urlretrieve()` uses a `urllib.URLOpener`, which doesn't have support for cookie handlers like `OpenerDirector` has.

What's the reason of this strange way of splitting functionality, and how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Not directly related, but I like to use [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/)(wrapper for libcurl), which handles cookies and other protocols much better.

Comment: @Keith thank you for your suggestion. I heard PycURL was hard to use though, but maybe I will give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`urlretrieve` is a old interface from `urllib`. It was there much before urllib2 came into existence. It does not have any session handling capabilities. It just downloads the files.  The updated `urllib2` provides much better way with the deal with sessions, passwords, proxies extra using its Handler interfaces OpenerDirector class. In order to just download the urls as files, you may just use the urlopen call of urllib2 using the same request object that you created. This will maintain the session.

Comment: OK, thanks for the information. I'll have to learn now how to save the request contents to a binary file.

Comment: That's easy, just open file object in 'wb' mode and whatever you read from urlopen().read() write to it and close it. That's it.